# FIWARE lab - My dockerhub image is created empty

Tags: fiware

I want to generate an image in FIWARE lab from Docker Hub.

I have tried different options and fiware lab does not give me an error, but it generates an empty image that cannot be instanced.

[Modal to create my own image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/my8tn.png)

Could you please give me an example of the url you use to create your own images from the docker hub?

Answer (score 0):

Currently FIWARE Lab only supports Virtual Machine images. There are no Docker images.

Maybe you can create you image and configure docker to run inside the Virtual Machine created from your image.

However, you can look at how a new image could be created using Openstack APIs and some qemu/libvirt tools here: https://github.com/jicarretero/FiwareImageTweak

The example there shows how to create a new image with docker and some dockers which will run when a new instance is created from an image generated this way.